# How To get "width: max-content" working in both IE11 and Chrome

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've got some bootstrap alerts used as information boxes on my pages. I use them to show the user how many filtered records are showing in a data grid, compared to how many actual records were returned. In Chrome, I make it a small box that is the width of the content, but IE ignores this and makes the alert be the width of the containing column div. I've looked at a bunch of other "fixes" for it, and tried them all to no effect.

The Chrome version:
[image]

The IE11 version:
[image]

The HTML (this is in an AngularJS 1.7.9, Bootstrap 4.4.1 page):

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 mt-2 px-0 mx-0">
    <div id="divResultsMessage"
         class="bg-info border border-info rounded-sm text-dark alert-fit-content mr-auto ml-auto">
        Showing {{(vm.results | filter: vm.searchFilter).length}} out of {{vm.results.length}} results returned.
    </div>
</div>
```

"alert-fit-content" is my own class:

```
.alert-fit-content {
    width: -moz-max-content !important;
    width: -webkit-max-content !important;
    width: -o-max-content !important;
    width: -ms-max-content !important;
    width: max-content !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    padding-right: 3px !important;
    padding-left: 3px !important;
}
```

I tried to cover all my bases with it, but it just doesn't work in IE, no matter what I try.

Comment: What you posted so far is not sufficient to repro the issue and, therefore, to test any potential solution. Please update with the rules applied to its parent. A [mcve] would be ideal. You could also remove the `!important`s. They're unnecessary.

Comment: Please read the [CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE11 [doesn't support](https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content) max-content

In this case, I believe you can get the result you're looking for using
`display: inline-block;`

```
.alert-fit-content {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
```

Comment: I know IE11 doesn't support it - what I was hoping for is a way to 'fake it'. Will using `display: inline-block` mess with anything in Chrome?

Comment: Should work fine in all browsers. Of course I'd recommend testing them to be completely sure though.

Comment: I wound up using a version of this as the fix, with a @media check for IE before applying it. Works like a charm. Now if I could just get BS4's ml-auto/mr-auto working in IE... Ahh, well. Onward. Thanks!